# How to secure data of user on firebase realtime data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning firebase for react native to make a simple note taking app, but from a user's point of view, I'm not sure how to safely store data on firebase realtime, meaning that dev(me) can read the data like notes already on firebase. Now. i'm using firebase to save data, it look like this

```
{
    "id":"some note Id",
    "header":"some note Header",
    "note": "This note is not secure at all",
    "date":"some date"
}
```

So how can i make these data secure, then i( or dev ) don't know what user was writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds you're looking for a way to end-to-end encrypt the user's data. While this is not built into Firebase itself, you can definitely add a layer on top of it.

I recommend reading some of these previous [questions on end-to-end encryption in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+end+to+end+encryption), and there also seem some promising results in this [search on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+end+to+end+encryption).